# Why `fastboot devices` fails in USB debugging mode and Downloading... -mode?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, fastboot

I enable developer mode in the phone, usb debugging and smart bootloader. 
I do where successfully boot to bootloader such that I see Android mascot with the text *Downloading... target Do not turn off!!* but I cannot get any ID from `fastboot devices`

```
root@masi:/home/masi# fastboot devices
root@masi:/home/masi# adb reboot bootloader
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
root@masi:/home/masi# fastboot devices
root@masi:/home/masi# fastboot devices
```

I have successfully completed the stages before in Windows 10, but Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8.x cause problems.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 gt-i9506
OS: CyanogenMod Temasek february/2016
Recovery: TWRP 2.8.x

PC: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: You expect fastboot to work in Download Mode? O_o On Samsung phones you're supposed to load stuff via Odin.

Comment: Sure, but what if you don't have TWRP installed yet (coming from stock)?

Comment: I don't really get your last comment. Recovery is supposed to be overwriting - the new version overwrites the old. Also, my previous comments are focused on the fastboot aspect of your question where there's no need to take TWRP's capability to update recovery into question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of the Android bootloader that usually features the **fastboot** server is called **aboot**.

As explained in [this](http://newandroidbook.com/Articles/aboot.html) article, the standard aboot derives from the [Little Kernel (LK)](https://www.codeaurora.org/blogs/little-kernel-based-android-bootloader) project. Almost any phone manufacturer then customized it and created its own bootloader. Follows an excerpt from the abovementioned article:

> All Bootloaders I've checked (including Samsung's and Amazon's) seem
>   to derive from LK (in fact printing out the "welcome to lk\n\n" from
>   its kmain), though Amazon's take steps to disable fastboot, as does
>   Samsung, which then uses their own custom App, called Odin.

In short, there's no way to use fastboot with Samsung devices. Only Odin is recognized (by the Loke component).

Comment: @Masi If I understood correctly (which I somehow doubt), your goal was to update from TWRP 2.8.x to 3.0.2. On Windows, this can be accomplished by booting the phone in Download mode and then using Odin to flash the recovery file, in the form of a **.tar.md5** file. On Linux, you can search for the **Heimdall** software, which does pretty much the same as Odin. *P.S.: despite the wording used in the section I quoted, and whether the Android bootloader may or may not derive from Little Kernel, the fact is that Samsung removed fastboot support, and **there is nothing we can do to fix it.***

Comment: @Masi Do not mistake recovery for bootloader/fastboot. You flash a recovery into the recovery partition of your device within bootloader/fastboot. "Only Odin/Heimdall" stands correct.

Comment: Then, it must be that I inserted a new recovery inside odin/heimdall.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer for this. However, I found a differential solution. Boot to recevory mode (mine TWRP 2.8.x), and flash the new recovery mode (TWRP 3.0.2) in Odin/Heimdall. This way, I could complete my target.